# How does eclipse resolve dependencies in a plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, equinox

It is known that any dependent plugin in a plugin gets loaded only when referenced portion (of dependent plugin) gets called up due to lazy loading concept . In that case, I have a doubt how does the dependencies in a plugin gets resolved. Is it via the name check in plugin registry ?

Answer (score 1):

Platform plug-in loader checks the plug-in dependencies in `MANIFEST.MF` file. The content of typical `MANIFEST.MF` file looks like:

```property
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Bundle-Name
Bundle-SymbolicName: XXX;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: XXX
Bundle-Vendor: %Bundle-Vendor
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
Require-Bundle: Plugin id 1,
 Plugin id 2,
 Plugin id 3,
 Plugin id 4
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Here **Require-Bundle** property lists all dependent plug-ins.

Read more about this [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html)
Use this [plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/metrics/) to check dependencies.